# Will Oracle use materialized view if I select count(*) from original table?

Tags: oracle11g, materialized-views

If I create materialized view my_view as select * from my_table group by my_column
Will Oracle use materialized view when I select count(*) from my_table?

Comment: Check the execution plan you you will see.

Comment: I have not done this yet, if it uses then I will create view.

Answer (score 0):

No, It will not use materialized view.